# How to have border radius in flutter video player?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to have border-radius for the video player in my flutter app. I tried to use border-radius to the parent Container(). But it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I got the result using ClipRRect. Just wrapped the video player with ClipRRect with some radius and it worked fine.

```
    ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        child: VideoPlayer(_controller)
     )
```

[image]

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: not working on Safari Web

Comment: Nice widget indeed

Answer (score 1):

Here is my updated solution code.

```
ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
          child: VideoPlayer(_controller)),
    ),
```